# Как получить подтверждение организации в business.google.com

Tags: seo, google-maps

Несколько раз отправляли заявку для получения письма с кодом подтверждения организации(donwatch.ru).Писем спустя 3 месяца и более мы так и не получили.Написали в помощь,пришло письмо ,в котором нас просили отравить

> Адрес электронной почты официального представителя компании,
>   зарегистрированный в корпоративном домене,

(которого у нас нету ,поэтому в ответ мы отправили обычный адрес эл.почты) и

> Письменное согласие на то, что мы передадим Ваш адрес электронной
>   почты представителю компании. Включите в сообщение следующую фразу: "Я
>   разрешаю передать мой адрес электронной почты указанному мной
>   представителю компании".

письмо отправили,но ответа так и не получили ,что делать?? 
1)Как получить подтверждение ???
2)Если получим код подтверждения ,в картах будут отображать адрес и место организации(в данный момент вместо конкретного адреса на картах виден красный круг)[ссылка на карты](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4/@47.224192,39.723952,5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x28bc3e2d9720f423!8m2!3d47.224192!4d39.723952) ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > (которого у нас нету ,поэтому в ответ мы отправили обычный адрес эл.почты)

Создать корпоративный адрес электронной почты. Это красиво, презентабельно и как-то по деловому. Сегодня не так сложно это сделать:
[Создание Корпоративной почты Google](https://gsuite.google.ru/intl/ru/products/gmail/) и [Создание Корпоративной почты Яндекс](https://pdd.yandex.ru/domains_add/). Для этого не надо обладать никакими навыками программирования и иметь специализированных знаний. Создается точно также как и обычная личная почта.

2. > 2)Если получим код подтверждения ,в картах будут отображать адрес и место организации(в данный момент вместо конкретного адреса на картах виден красный круг)

По вашей ссылке виден адрес, значит вы получили код подтверждения=) Поздравляю!
Но корпоративный e-mail все таки создайте.